# Facebook Login Button Not Working in Android Upper 5.0

Tags: android, facebook, button, authentication

I have a problem with login facebook in android. I am slightly new in android facebook sdk. In my emulator facebook login works fine but in real phone it does not work. Also I tried 7.0 it also makes problem in emulator. I could not find any same problems on web. So here is my error message.

**Thanks for any help.**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent$Builder;
                  at com.facebook.internal.CustomTab.openCustomTab(CustomTab.java:47)
                  at com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity.onCreate(CustomTabMainActivity.java:67)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
```

Also My Code in Below..

*

> This Code works with emulator and below 5.0 version androids. Some > people said that it can be related with chrome-custom tab. But it > works with chrome installed devices.

*

**This is my manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wrexsoft.canturgut.mobileclassapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".OpenScreen"
        android:label="Init Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignInScreen"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**This is my activity java file...**

```
public class OpenScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView headline;

Button openScreen_button_signin;
Button openScreen_button_kusignin;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

private DatabaseReference patideDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_screen);

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");



    patideDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(OpenScreen.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Proceed data...");
            progressDialog.show();
            String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
            Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                    // Get facebook data from login
                    Bundle bFacebookData = getFacebookData(object);
                    String username = bFacebookData.get("first_name").toString();
                    String userSurname = bFacebookData.get("last_name").toString();
                    String email = bFacebookData.get("email").toString();

                    HashMap<String, String> userData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    userData.put("Name",username+" "+userSurname );
                    userData.put("Email",email);

                    patideDatabase.push().setValue(userData);

                }
            });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Login Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Problem connecting to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    headline = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.headline);

    openScreen_button_signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openscreen_button_signin);
    openScreen_button_kusignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openscreen_button_kusissignin);

    openScreen_button_signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra("signinType","normal");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    openScreen_button_kusignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra("signinType","kusis");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent    data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

private Bundle getFacebookData(JSONObject object) {

    try {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String id = object.getString("id");


        bundle.putString("idFacebook", id);
        if (object.has("first_name"))
            bundle.putString("first_name", object.getString("first_name"));
        if (object.has("last_name"))
            bundle.putString("last_name", object.getString("last_name"));
        if (object.has("email"))
            bundle.putString("email", object.getString("email"));

        return bundle;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        return bundle;
    }
}}
```

Just in case I am using FireBase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the original Facebook App installed on your crashing device? 
1. Install FB, do not log in, rerun your app and try again.
2. Try with pre-logged in on FB

Comment: Saolun murat bey